# Difficulty placing 2 WHERE's in SQL query

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with my SQL query?

It keeps returning the following error at the `WHERE building_id=:building_id`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':building_id AND WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ts_roompref '
>   at line 5: SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount FROM ts_room WHERE
>   building_id=:building_id AND WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM
>   ts_roompref JOIN ts_request ON ts_roompref.request_id =
>   ts_request.roompref_id AND day_id = 1 AND period_id = 1 WHERE
>   ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE building_id=:building_id AND
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 1
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
```

I've got a SQL table here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30297/8

Comment: You don't need the 2nd WHERE. Just take that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the second `WHERE` keyword.

This won't compile in SQL Fiddle because of `:buildingid`.

[Here's a working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30297/15).

Comment: @methuselah What's your question?

Comment: No worries I figured it out :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need second WHERE after AND

```
... WHERE building_id=:building_id AND NOT EXISTS ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `WHERE`

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 
WHERE building_id=:building_id AND

  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref 
      JOIN ts_request 
      ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
      AND day_id = 1 
      AND period_id = 1
    WHERE 
      ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

After `AND` you aren't supposed to write `WHERE` a second time.